# Is there a UWP equivalent to PathGeometry.GetPointAtFractionLength(double progress, out System.Windows.Point point, out System.Windows.Point tangent)?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I am in the process of converting a WPF application into a UWP application and I haven't been able to find an equivalent function to PathGeometry.GetPointAtFractionLength() as described in the title. I was wondering if anybody has found a way to implement equivalent functionality in a UWP application. I've looked up the source code for this function already and it utilized a wide array of dependencies/other functions that I would like to avoid having to use. This is basically the last piece of conversion that's left for me, so it would mean the world if somebody knew how to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such api in UWP [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.PathGeometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.pathgeometry) class and it only contains `Figures` that use to store `PathFigure`. For your requirement, the better way is convert the WPF app to UWP  with desktop-bridge. For detail steps please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-root).